# How to make solid soluble support surface with Prusaslicer?

Tags: prusaslicer, multi-material, pva

I am printing on a Prusa i3 MK3S+ with MMU2S module using PVA+ soluble material and PLA. Slicing with PrusaSlicer 2.3.1. This question is more about slicing and is probably printer-independent.

My problem is the default pattern makes the surface not smooth. See the attached screenshot from PrusaSlicer (picture from the bottom side, for clarity I hid the lowest layers to make the interface visible):

[image: PrusaSlicer 3D rendering of a model from the bottom side]

The resulting object looks like this:

[image: Actual printed model with printing errors]

What I wish the slicing would look like:

[image: PrusaSlicer 3D rendering of what the model should look like]

Any ideas on how to make such a pattern or other ideas to make it better? It doesn't matter if the support is hard to remove because it's soluble anyway.

The simplified STL model: https://zouppen.iki.fi/poista/pirra.stl

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the Support Interface Layers.

In PrusaSlicer, enable **Advanced** or **Expert** mode, and under **Print Settings** ▶ **Support Material** ▶ **Options for support material and raft** you can decrease the Interface Layers to zero, and only the support structure will remain.

Keep in mind, this will affect *ALL* supports in the model, however.

Comment: Combined with pattern spacing 0 and interface layers 0 it kind of does it but it also disables interface which wastes way too much PVA. The usage of support material is even higher than in the actual object. So in practice it is unfortunately too slow and expensive solution. See video: https://zouppen.iki.fi/poista/no_interface.mp4

Comment: Try without decreasing the pattern spacing, or decreasing it by half instead. Your print is small enough that it can likely bridge those small gaps in the support. Testing in prusaslicer, 1.25mm pattern spacing might be around the sweetspot